# Connecting to azure database using jtds from android

Tags: android, ssl, azure, noclassdeffounderror, jtds

I'm designing an android app to directly connect to an azure database using the open source jtds driver version 1.2.7. I've successfully connected to an sql server express database, so I know it works. When attempting to connect to the azure database, though, I get an error. Here's the stacktrace:

```
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.SocketFactoriesSUN$TdsTlsSocketFactory.factory(SocketFactoriesSUN.java:174)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.SocketFactoriesSUN$TdsTlsSocketFactory.getFactory(SocketFactoriesSUN.java:157)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.SocketFactoriesSUN$TdsTlsSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactoriesSUN.java:86)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.enableEncryption(SharedSocket.java:332)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.negotiateSSL(TdsCore.java:554)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:350)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:188)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
06-06 17:03:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:209)
```

It looks like the problem is the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext` but I have no idea what to do about this. I believe that force encryption is turned on at the database, but I did not set it up and I don't have permission to mess with those settings. Any idea what to do about this error?

Comment: Can you show the code that generating the error?  Also, I understand connecting to SQL Server using JTDS but Azure is a different animal. I haven't found anyone that is able to connect to Azure using JTDS.